# my psvm class doesnt run the other classes and methods

Tags: java, class, methods

My program is not running. It must be something with calling in the classes from my `psvm`.

I have inserted my main class and I want the class with the following methods to run. It runs the program, but the class: course with its methods is not activated.

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Course task1 = new Course();
    task1.Assignment1();

    }}
```

#### The other class

```
public class Course {

    CourseGrades[] course;

    public void Assignment1() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


            System.out.println("Welcome to students database");
            System.out.println("Enter a to enter a student");
            char choice = sc.next().charAt(0);

            if (choice > 'z' || choice > 'a') {
                System.out.println("Invalid choice");

            } else {

                switch (choice) {

                    case 'a':
                        numbers();
                        break;
                    case 'b':
                        entering();
                        break;
                    case 'c':
                        printCourse();
                        break;

                }
            }
        }


    public void numbers() {

        System.out.println("Enter how many courses taken ");
        Scanner numbers = new Scanner(System.in);
        int courses = numbers.nextInt();
        CourseGrades[] course = new CourseGrades[courses];

    }

    public void entering() {

        for (int i = 0; i < course.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter  coursename");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String courseName = sc.nextLine();
            course[i] = new CourseGrades();
            course[i].setName(courseName);
            System.out.println("Enter grade");
            Scanner grade = new Scanner(System.in);
            course[i].setGrade(i);

        }
    }

    public void printCourse() {

        System.out.println("Printing out courses and grades");

        for (int i = 0; i < course.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(" name 2" + course[i].getName() + " grade" + course[i].getGrade());

        }

    }
}
```

#### Getters and setters

```
public class CourseGrades {

private String name;
private int grade;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(int grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    } 
}
```

Comment: First Follow the Naming conversations.its little difficult to understand your code without naming conversations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple classes in your code then you should always save with the class which having main() method (in this case Main.java), and that class only should be contains public access specifier. I run same code in my IDE. i am run your code successfully in MY IDE:

See the code:

```
         public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Course task1 = new Course();
    task1.Assignment1();

    }

 }

// The other class

class Course {

    CourseGrades[] course;

    public void Assignment1() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


            System.out.println("Welcome to students database");
            System.out.println("Enter a to enter a student");
            char choice = sc.next().charAt(0);

            if (choice > 'z' || choice > 'a') {
                System.out.println("Invalid choice");

            } else {

                switch (choice) {

                    case 'a':
                        numbers();
                        break;
                    case 'b':
                        entering();
                        break;
                    case 'c':
                        printCourse();
                        break;

                }
            }
        }


    public void numbers() {

        System.out.println("Enter how many courses taken ");
        Scanner numbers = new Scanner(System.in);
        int courses = numbers.nextInt();
        CourseGrades[] course = new CourseGrades[courses];

    }

    public void entering() {

        for (int i = 0; i < course.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter  coursename");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String courseName = sc.nextLine();
            course[i] = new CourseGrades();
            course[i].setName(courseName);
            System.out.println("Enter grade");
            Scanner grade = new Scanner(System.in);
            course[i].setGrade(i);

        }
    }

    public void printCourse() {

        System.out.println("Printing out courses and grades");

        for (int i = 0; i < course.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(" name 2" + course[i].getName() + " grade" + course[i].getGrade());

        }

    }
}

// Getters and setters
class CourseGrades {

private String name;
private int grade;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(int grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }


}
```

Results:

```
       Welcome to students database
        Enter a to enter a student
        a
        Enter how many courses taken 
        3
```

Comment: your edit of your code works perfectly, where precisely did you change it,

Comment: tried yours edit out on mine, it runs perfectly. Where specifically did you change in the code, because i really wanna know?

Comment: @Rangerguy, Well I removed unwanted public access specifier infront of Course and CourseGrades classes.

Comment: My suggestion is use any IDE for avoiding this type of code issues.